# Using DQL select only entities that have given count of associated objects

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

How can I filter in DQL entities that have given count of attached, associated objects?

For example:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $qb->where('COUNT(u.moods) > 1');
```

Where u.moods is one-to-many relation for user?

Comment: I think there are two ways, one is to just count the number objects in your ArrayCollection for the associated objects. Or, you can actually query the associated entity having (WHERE <entity_id> IN ()).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query builder configuration.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb
    ->select(array('u'))
    ->from('User', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u.moods', 'm')
    ->having(
        $qb->expr()->gt(
            $qb->expr()->count('m'), 1
        )
    );

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Or if you prefer DQL

```
$dql = "SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.moods m HAVING COUNT(m) > 1";

$query = $this->createQuery($dql);

return $query->getResult();
```